Amendments to the United States Constitution
The 22nd Amendment to the US Constitution limits the President to two terms in office.
Suppose a President successfully campaigns for either repealing this amendment, or overriding it with another, allowing a President unlimited terms in office.
Will it be legal for it to apply to the incumbent, or can it only apply to future Presidents?

As of now there are two close votes for 'opinion' based, and one for 'needs clarity'. So from my comment:
Is there any protection under US Law or Constitution that prevents a sitting President becoming President for life, subject to election?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I don't think this question is deserving of a minus-4 score. It is interesting enough and has some good answers

Legally, sure.  The Twenty-second amendment could have applied to the incumbent president at the time of ratification but the drafters specifically excluded that possibility

But this Article shall not apply to any person holding the office of
President when this Article was proposed by the Congress, and shall
not prevent any person who may be holding the office of President, or
acting as President, during the term within which this Article becomes
operative from holding the office of President or acting as President
during the remainder of such term.

Politically, having an amendment impact the current president would make an already difficult ratification process even more challenging.  Members of the opposition party in Congress and in the various state legislatures would be much less willing to vote to change the terms for the current president as opposed to a hypothetical future president that is potentially from their party.

Yes, and Howard Truman did try and run for another term, but was upset by a certain Estes Kefauver in the New Hampshire primary.

Harry Truman, you mean? AFAIK Harry is his actual given name.

From the comments what you really are asking about is what may prevent such a situation.
The answer is - nothing really.
To create a dictatorship in the US one needs to amend the Constitution, but if one has enough support to do that - there's nothing that can stop them. This is called a "Gödel's Loophole". Gödel observed that by incrementally amending the Constitution it may be changed from defining a democracy to something else.
Currently it requires a vote of 2/3rds of each chamber of Congress, and ratification by 3/4ths of the US States (38 out of currently 50) to pass a Constitutional amendment. If there's enough support to overcome these high thresholds, the Constitution can be changed to anything at all.
Whatever the Constitution says is legal - is legal.

Luckily for the general person in the USA, there are deeply entrenched geo-rivalries that preclude great swaths of Americans from agreeing on anything. That is why calling somebody a Yankee in Texas is a terrible insult.

@NeilMeyer, yes, but then again - there's a significant effort being made to keep about 2/3rd of US States under Republican control regardless of the actual population needs or wants. So all that's needed in this scenario is to capture just a few more.

The Constitution applies to whatever its terms say it applies to. It is always speaking.
You are asking about a hypothetical amendment that repeals the 22nd Amendment.
There are no restrictions on the content of an amendment (even reducing a state's equal suffrage in the Senate can by the terms of the constitution be accomplished with the state's consent).
A hypothetical amendment that simply repeals the 22nd Amendment would just leave the Constitution without the current restrictions. A Constitution without those restrictions would not restrict.
Alternatively, the hypothetical amendment could include transitional provisions, clarifying for example that any person who was barred due to the then 22nd Amendment from being elected to a third term would continue to be barred from being elected to a third term, even after repeal of the 22nd Amendment.
I can imagine many alternative transitional provisions.
